# How to create a postgres backup of all databases with pg_dumpall compatible with pg_restore

Tags: pg-dump, pg-restore

I want to implement a backup/restore strategy for a postgres instance, and I'm having some struggle when choosing the most appropriate and flexible way to do it.

On one side, **pg_dumpall** allows to dump all the databases plus roles and tablespaces so it's the most complete way to backup the instance.
On the other side, **pg_dumpall** does not allow to dump the data in custom format, which is the one compatible by **pg_restore**.

So, if I have correctly understood, **pg_restore** cannot be used in combination with **pg_dumpall**, and I should perform **pg_dump** on each database, plus dump roles and tablespace info on a separate script in order to use **pg_restore**. Is this correct?